# Printing ID for a GORM object

Tags: grails, grails-orm

In my GORM objects I use the `@ToString` annotation. For example,

```
@ToString(includeNames=true, includePackage=false)
class BasketSet {
    ...
```

I don't explicitly add an Id field as I use the GORM default Id for the GORM objects, My problem is that the Id doesn't get printed in the toString().  Any ideas?

Comment: so why not implement String toString(){this.id}

Comment: I want a neat / grails / groovy way for all GORM objects

Answer (score 1):

There is always the posibility to create your own toString

```
class BasketSet{
    String toString(){
            return "${this.id}"
        }
}
```

Comment: Why not only `this.id` in place of `"${this.id}"`?

Comment: Yeah sorry, there is not a particular reason.
It is just because im used to it.

If you do want to return a more complex message like
"The id of BasketSet is 2" I would use ${this.id}. 
 
      return "The id of BasketSet is ${this.id}", 
so I dont have to concatenate Strings.

But either way is just fine.